# distance between variables remains the same.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have three variables, let's call them a, b, and c. Currently, they have the following values:

$a = 5$

$b = 3$

$c = 6$

I want to modify the value of one of these variables while ensuring that the distance between each pair of variables remains the same. In other words, I need to maintain an equidistant relationship among them.

For instance, if I change the value of '$a$', the differences between '$a$' and '$b$', and '$a$' and '$c$' should remain constant.

Could someone please provide me with a mathematical expression or a formula to achieve this? Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to find all $a$ such that $|b-a|=2$ and $|c-a|=1$. This is a problem on complex numbers.

Comment: yes all  simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the relative distances among the variables the same and you change $a$ to $a+x$ then just change $b$ to $b+x$ and $c$ to $c+x$.

So in your example, if you change $a$ to $2$ then $x = -3$ and $b$ becomes $3-3=0$ and $c$ becomes $6-3=3$.

You are just sliding the triple $a,b,c$ to a different place on the number line.